# Using Linq to query repository returning invalid results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a search form that accepts multiple words when search a directory. When the user searches for a term where each word is >= 3 char in length, the result returns as expected. However, if a term contains a word with < 3 chars, it returns a whole lot more results which are invalid to the filter requirements.

In my repository, I have the below code, where `value` is passed in and `employees` is the DbSet.

```
var searchTerms = value.Split(' ')
                .Select(v => v.Trim().ToLower())
                .ToList();

var data = this.employees
                .Where(e => searchTerms.Any(s => e.fname.Contains(s)) ||
                    searchTerms.Any(s => e.lname.Contains(s)) ||
                    searchTerms.Any(s => e.dept.name.Contains(s)) ||
                    e.dept.dept_subs
                        .Where(d => searchTerms
                            .Any(s => d.name.Contains(s)))
                                .Any())
                .Where(e => e.isActive == true)
                .OrderBy(e => e.lname)
                .ThenBy(e => e.fname)
                .AsEnumerable();
```

So the question remains, Why is the query breaking on two character words and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Okay. it turns out that it isn't limited to 2 characters.

The result format is below. If a subdepartment empty, it'll be just the name line.

```
LastName, FirstName
SubDepartment, Department
```

Search for '*ali*' returns

```
Adams, Nadiyah
Logistics, Resources Directorate

Ahmed, W*ali*ul
```

a search for '*jr*'

```
Brooks, *Jr*, Cecil
Customer Service Center, Program Administration Directorate 

Brown *Jr*, Peter
Document Control and Data Management, Operations Directorate
```

a search for '*li*'

```
Abdullah, *Li*ndsey

Abney, James
E*li*gibility, Enrollment Verification, Operations Directorate

Abrams, Charles
Customer Service Center, Program Administration Directorate
```

**UPDATE 2**

As requested in the comments, here are the three classes:

```
public partial class dept
{
    ctor()
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<dept_sub> dept_subs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<employee> employees { get; set; }
}

public partial class dept_sub
{
    ctor()
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int dept_id { get; set; }    
    public virtual dept dept { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<employee> employees { get; set; }
}

public partial class employee
{
    ctor()    
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dept_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dept_sub_id { get; set; }
    public virtual dept dept { get; set; }
    public virtual dept_sub dept_sub { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample data?

Comment: Also if `value` has multiple spaces between the words you will end up with some empty strings in the `searchTerms` array, which will cause all records to match.

Comment: If you notice, Nadiyah and Charles both should not have returned

Comment: @wdosanjos Thanks. I'll take a look at that real quick.

Comment: Do the above examples include the sub departments as well?

Comment: @wdosanjos no luck. Same results.

Comment: @KMoussa Abney, James is a valid result where sub departments was true

Comment: @Ian I am a bit confused by the example data, which parts are departments and which are sub-departments?

Comment: @KMoussa added format explanation

Comment: @Ian thanks, is each employee a member of one sub dept or more? The reason I am asking is ur query looks for the match in all sub depts for the department of the employee

Comment: First your sub department query looks odd to me.  Hard for me to read or test.  Can you post a simple class that would make this code compile?  Could fix easily then.  Also your call to `AsEnumerable()` is basically a no-op.  You can remove that.

Comment: @KMoussa an employee may only be assigned to none or one sub department.

Comment: @Ian so isn't you query incorrect then to look for a match in all sub departments (`e.depts.depts_sub.Where(..`)?

Comment: @Zer0 Sample models added

Comment: @KMoussa That might be it. Let me check. The original developer did a horrible job in normalizing the db. I had to JsonIgnore some of the properties in the models.

Comment: @Ian That is definitely not normalized.  You have both departments and sub departments in the employee itself, then sub departments appear again as part of a department.  Seems foobar.  Plus the sub departments also have a collection of employees.  Maybe convenience but code smell to me.  Also think KMoussa is on the right path here now that I see your model.

Answer (score 0):

@KMoussa and @Zer0 led me to finding the underlying problem. I also implemented @wdosanjos recommendation.

The `employee` object references both the `dept` and `dept_sub`. Rather than going in a round about method with the `employee` asking the `dept_sub` to ask the `dept` what it's name is, I rerouted the query to jumping the chain of command (since it's mapped) and adjusting the query like below.

I adjusted the code as follows and it seems to be returning better results.

```
// trim off any whitespace on the ends
string term = value.Trim();

// remove and replace extended spaces with a single space
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
term = regex.Replace(term, " ");

// break down the property into a collection of strings
List<string> searchTerms = term.Split(' ')
    .Select(v => v.Trim().ToLower())
    .ToList();

// query the dbset
IEnumerable<employee> data = this.employees
    .Where(e => searchTerms.Any(s => e.fname.Contains(s)) ||
                searchTerms.Any(s => e.lname.Contains(s)) ||
                searchTerms.Any(s => e.dept.name.Contains(s)) ||
                searchTerms.Any(s => e.dept_sub.name.Contains(s))) // new line
                // e.dept.dept_subs.Where(d => 
                //      searchTerms.Any(s => d.name.Contains(s))).Any())
    .Where(e => e.isActive == true)
    .OrderBy(e => e.lname)
    .ThenBy(e => e.fname);
```